# Insert a commit without merging

Tags: git

I have the current situation

```
A ----- D
 \
  B - C (master)
```

Now I would like to insert the `D` commit **without merging**, e.g. **not changing the contents** of the *future* commits `B` and `C`.

Basically rewriting the parents of the `B` commit (and hence all the other commits upstream).

In the end I would like to have without manual interaction:

```
A - D - B - C
```

Comment: updated question: the whole operation should happen in batch mode, sorry for not being precise enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the proper way to introduce a new commit to the history without changing its contents (beside the commit SHA of course) is to use an intermediate git graft.

In the following example I assume that there were no previous grafts:

```
# use a graft to temporarily change the parent of B to be D
echo "$SHA_B $SHA_D" > .git/info/grafts
# apply the grafts, changing the SHAs of the commits B...C
git filter-branch
# remove old pending commits
git gc
# remove the no longer needed grafts
rm .git/info/grafts
```

This leaves all commit contents (files and folders) untouched.

Answer (score 1):

The action you're looking for is `rebase` in interactive mode.

```
git checkout C
git cherry-pick D # Now: A - B - C -D
git rebase -i A
<reorder commits>
git log
```

The `--interactive / -i` option will open up the history in your editor, allowing you to jumble things up as much as you like. You can even squash multiple commits together or eliminate some entirely.

If you want to be totally mundane, you could also do it this way:

```
git checkout A
git cherry-pick D B C
```

Comment: It may be obvious to the OP, but just to be sure - note that the B and C commits will become B' and C' - in other words, new commits with new hashes.

Comment: Is there a way to shortcut the whole order if there are a lot of commits between `B` and `C`?

Comment: @dh82 You could use a range specifier such as `B..C`

Comment: This is ridiculous. Why would you ever have to cherrypick D?

Comment: this does modify the contents of `B` and `C`, the future commits

Answer (score 1):

batch mode would be done on things you have in your current branches history. In this case you are looking at either the history of D or the history of your master. The simplest thing to do here is:

```
git rebase D
```

(assuming you have master checked out already) Why do you need this to be done in batch mode?

Comment: in your case tags on `B` and `C` keep on pointing to the old objects?

Comment: same commits, no different than cherrypicking individual commits. Take a look how the DAG (directed acyclic graph) works.

Comment: rebase will merge, so it will affect the future commits, this is not what I want.

Comment: @dh82 There is no way to rewrite history in git without invalidating the hashes (unless you can produce an SHA-1 collision). That's by design. Your downstream **will** notice.

Comment: rebasing is not merging. rebasing is applying commits as a set of patches onto a new starting point. There can be conflicts but these are not merge conflicts per se. Cherrypicking does the same thing. You can just take the snapshots (or trees) of the other commits. But this should be equivalent of using the "theirs" strategy to conflicts.

Comment: @Borealid I don't care if the hashes change, I simply do not want the contents (AKA the checked out data) to change, rebase does that

Comment: @Adam Dymitruk yes, but it ultimetaly changes the contents of the following commits, which is not what I want